# User management system feedback

Tags: forum, user-management

Users belong to 1 group. Every group has specific rights (defined in the group_rights table).
The group_rights:

```
user_management:
    0: nothing
    1: may warn users
    2: may suspend users
    3: may edit/delete users

group_management:
    0: nothing
    1: may view groups
    2: may add groups
    3: may give root access to groups

forum_management:
    0: nothing
    1: view in backend, but can't do anything
    2: edit fora
    3: add fora

global_access:
    1: whole group suspended
    2: normal access
    3: root access
```

So the user group would look like this:

```
======== groups ========
Id: 1
Name: users
Description: All the registered normal users

======== group_rights ========
id: 1
group_id: 1
global_access: 2
user_management: 0
group_management: 0
forum_management: 0
```

And the admin group like this:

```
======== groups ========
Id: 2
Name: admin
Description: This admin group has got extra rights

======== group_rights ========
id: 2
group_id: 2
global_access: 2
user_management: 3
group_management: 2
forum_management: 3
```

And the admin+ group like this:

```
======== groups ========
Id: 3
Name: admin+
Description: Admin+ is for only a few users, like the owner

======== group_rights ========
id: 3
group_id: 3
global_access: 3
user_management: 3
group_management: 3
forum_management: 3
```

And the moderator group like this:

```
======== groups ========
Id: 4
Name: moderator
Description: Global moderators

======== group_rights ========
id: 4
group_id: 4
global_access: 2
user_management: 2
group_management: 1
forum_management: 2
```

Could you give some feedback? I know it isn't perfect and can be better, so maybe you could help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I typically set up users/roles/rights:

```
actions
    id              unsigned int(P)
    description     varchar(255)

|---|----------------------------|
|id | description                |
|---|----------------------------|
| 1 | Warn users                 |
| 2 | Suspend users              |
| 3 | Edit/delete users          |
| 4 | View groups                |
| 5 | Add groups                 |
| 6 | Give root access to groups |
| 7 | View backend               |
| 8 | Edit fora                  |
| 9 | Add fora                   |
|---|----------------------------|

groups
    id              unsigned int(P)
    name            varchar(50) // Admins, Moderators, etc.

|---|------------|
|id | name       |
|---|------------|
| 1 | Admins     |
| 2 | Moderators |
|---|------------|

groups_actions
    id              unsigned int(P)
    group_id        unsigned int(F groups.id)
    action_id       unsigned int(F actions.id)

|---|----------|-----------|
|id | group_id | action_id |
|---|----------|-----------|
| 1 |     1    |     3     |
| 2 |     1    |     5     |
| 3 |     1    |     9     |
| 4 |     2    |     2     |
| 5 |     2    |     4     |
| 6 |     2    |     8     |
|---|----------|-----------|

users
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    username            varchar(32)
    password            varbinary(255)
    email               varchar(255)

|---|----------|----------|-------|
|id | username | password | email |
|---|----------|----------|-------|
| 1 | user1    | ****     | xxxx  |
| 2 | user2    | ****     | xxxx  |
| 3 | user3    | ****     | xxxx  |
|...| ...      | ...      | ...   |
|---|----------|----------|-------|

users_groups
    id              unsigned int(P)
    user_id         unsigned int(F users.id)
    group_id        unsigned int(F groups.id)

|---|---------|----------|
|id | user_id | group_id |
|---|---------|----------|
| 1 | 1       | 1        |
| 2 | 2       | 2        |
| 3 | 3       | 1        |
| 4 | 3       | 2        |
|---|---------|----------|

User 1 is an Admin
User 2 is a Moderator
User 3 is both an Admin and Moderator
```